# Android - Is it possible to run @Composable function via context etc

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As we know, in order to run a `@Composable` function, it is necessary to have a `@Composable` function again.

We call `@Composable` functions with the `setContent { }` method in the Activity. It seems that this is the beginning of the flow. But can I call a `@Composable` function without the starting point `setContent { }` method? For example via a context?

Comment: You can get fragment/activity from the `context` and call `setContent` on it. It'll replace your current view tree.

Comment: Does this remove the background image? For example, when only the dialog part shows the dialog made with @Composable on the screen?

Comment: Anything you've inside previously called `setContent` will be removed